# Is it possible to Clone a Dinosaur with a full strand of their DNA?

Tags: genetics, evolution, dna

If you have a full strand of Dinosaur DNA would it be possible to make it living and hatch a dinosaur? Or would it be a failure? Could you use a bird or alligator, for replacein

Comment: “A full strand”? Spot the mistake.